# Aircraft Specific Type Rating Check-ride vs. Airline Transport Pilot (ATP) Check-ride

Tags: atpl

When looking at the Airman Certification Standards (ACS) for “Airline Transport Pilot and Type Rating for Airplane” I have interpreted the level of precision (e.g., hdg. +/- 10°) on a type rating (e.g., B737, A320, etc.) check-ride to be the exact same precision required when an applicant is testing for an addition of an ATP license (i.e., check-ride). For example, in the ATP & TR for Airplane ACS for normal take-off, the pilot must maintain climb airspeed +/-5 knots. For a Type Rating check-ride, I gather the same precision (i.e., +/-5 knots) is required since the document title includes "Type Ratings"?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that would cause you to question this? Otherwise I don't see any reason to doubt that your interpretation is correct.

Comment: No, just the general rule that nothing in dealing with the regulatory authorities is ever as straightforward as it may at first appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a question posed by the OP.  The level of precision flying required of a type rating applicant is the same as what is required if applying for an ATP certificate.

The FAA, rightfully so, considers anyone who flies a type rated airplane to need to have the necessary piloting skill, CRM, ADM and leadership skills required of any ATP certificate holder.

The oral portion of the practical test for the type rating versus an ATP certificate is almost identical with some exceptions.  An ATP applicant will need to answer questions they were found deficient on during the written test as well as an additional 5 subject areas.

- Task I.C. Weather Information
- Task I.D. High Altitude Aerodynamics
- Task I.E. Air Carrier Operations
- Task I.F. Human Factors
- Task I.G. The Code of Federal Regulations.

There will be no difference in the flying portion of the practical test between a type rating and an ATP certificate.